# differentiation of fractional part of $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the differentiation of fractional part of $x$?

Since the slope of $\{x\}$ is $1$ so that derivative of $\{x\}$ should be $1$. Is it correct or not

Comment: do u understand how some functions can be non-differentiable?

Comment: Sorry to say but I can't understand

Comment: U know limits. Like left hand limits and right hand limits. Just like that for a function to be differentiated, the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative must exist and be equal.  To know more about it search and read about the topic "Continuity and Differentiation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to differentiate the fractional part of x when $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is because the graph of $\{x\}$ is not continuous. So its derivative does not exist.

Why its derivative does not exist? If you look at the right-hand derivative and left-hand derivative of the integral values of $x$, they are not the same. For a function to be differentiated, the left-hand derivative and right-hand derivative must be the same. Hence, its derivative does not exist at $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

However, other than the integral values of $\{x\}$ the derivatives exist. The derivative for other values of $x$ is evidently 1. To generalise the derivative of ($\frac{d}{dx}\{x\}, x \in \mathbb{R-Z} = 1$).

Answer (score 5):

Your function $\{x\}$ has derivative $1$ as you note, except $\{x\}$ has jumps (of $-1$) at each integer.  In the theory of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), the derivative of a unit jump at $0$ is a measure called $\delta$.  So
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\{x\} = 1 - \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \delta(x-n)
\tag{1}$$
(This is a simple example of a [Lebesgue decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem) of a signed measure.)
What does it mean?  For example, we may write a Stieltjes integral like this
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \varphi(x)\;d\{x\} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \varphi(x)\;dx - \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \varphi(n)
\tag{2}$$
for nice enough functions $\varphi$.  For example, this works when $\varphi$ is continuous with compact support.

Comment: $\varphi$ being continuous with compact support is merely a sufficient condition here, not a necessary one, right?

Comment: @user76284: of course.  That condition will easily insure that all three terms in (2) exist.

Answer (score 3):

Is the function continuous? *No*

So the derivative is undefined for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1$ everywhere else.

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{Z}$  then {x} become zero and derivative of zero is zero then why it is undefined

Comment: Because the limit from left is one and the limit from right is zero - the function is noncontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate this only at points $x\notin\mathrm Z,$ since exactly at such points $[x]$ is discontinuous and thus perforce not differentiable. With this proviso, since you have $\{x\}=x-[x],$ then we have that $$\left(\{x\}\right)'=\left(x-[x]\right)'=1-0=1,$$ provided $x\notin\mathrm Z.$